# How can I use field selectors in the LinkedIn gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, linkedin-api

I have been trying to use the LinkedIn gem (0.3.6) to search. I can successfully authenticate and search with just keywords but I want to be able to use the field selectors so that my results contain more than just id, first name, last name.

I have been unsuccessful when doing what is in the spec

```
 fields = [{:people => [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :public_profile_url, :picture_url]}, :num_results]
        client.search(:first_name => 'Giliardi', :last_name => 'Pires', :fields => fields)
```

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: By pulling down the code and running the rspec locally it works but like you I cannot pull it out and get it to work. I will crank away at it some more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the gem client.search does not match the github client.search... and the spec is based on the github client.search. And to be honest I cannot figure out how to get it to work with the Gem search. They do not include a spec for search in the Gem example provided in the api_spec.rb (no search_spec) gives a 404: `client.search(:first_name => "Javan", :fields => ["num_results", "total"])`

My suggestion would to be build the gem from the [github source](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) and use the selectors.

Gem:

```
def search(options={})
      path = "/people-search"
  options = { :keywords => options } if options.is_a?(String)

  if fields = options.delete(:fields)
    path +=":(#{fields.map{ |f| f.to_s.gsub("_","-") }.join(',')})"
  end

  options = format_options_for_query(options)

  result_json = get(to_uri(path, options))
  Mash.from_json(result_json)
end
```

GitHub:

```
def search(options={})
  path = "/people-search"

  if options.is_a?(Hash)
    fields = options.delete(:fields)
    path += field_selector(fields) if fields
    puts path
  end

  options = { :keywords => options } if options.is_a?(String)
  options = format_options_for_query(options)

  result_json = get(to_uri(path, options))

  Mash.from_json(result_json)
end
```